# preg match php a-zA-Z0-9 and space

Tags: php

```
if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i', $getname)) {
```

i use this preg_match pattern to check if a string in php contains other charachters than `a-zA-Z0-9`. i want to add to the pattern the space...i use '`/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i'` but is not working ... how should i do it?

i want to allow spaces including `a-zA-Z0-9`

Comment: Can't reproduce: var_dump(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i', 'az ')); // int(1) var_dump(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i', 'az ')); // int(0)

Comment: For what input is it failing?

Comment: if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i', 'helo helo')) {
    // The string contains characters other than a-z and A-Z and space
echo "AL";
mysql_close($con);
exit;
}

Comment: "I want to allow" - you do realize that the If-block will be executed if it contains DISallowed character?

Comment: `preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i', 'helo helo')` works for me. The `if` statement **is not** executed, exactly as required. Or do you want something else?

Comment: @stefanson: As you accepted @yoda's answer, you seemed to formulated the problem wrong (you event put a wrong comment in the code. You wrote `// The string contains characters other than a-z and A-Z and space` but actually you want `// The string only contains a-z and A-Z and space`. Without the a clear problem description it is difficult to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match ('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', $getname)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', 'string')
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-'_' ']/", 'string')

if you want to use space in your input field then you have to use this ' ' not this ''.

mention space between ' '